# Wikipedia API - searching in lists instead of categories (JSON, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to figure out a way to use the mediawiki API to find relevant pages in wikipedia lists.  For example, here is a list of all battles from 1901 - 2000:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battles_1901%E2%80%932000

What I would like to do is find all entries there that have the string "April 3" in their description.  And then get those JSON objects to then parse into my HTML.  I have been working on this all afternoon and I cannot find a way to do this.  I also don't have a great grasp of Wikipedia's API, so any help would be much appreciated.

The best I've gotten is a query like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=List_of_battles_1901%E2%80%932000&prop=links

But that just gives me a bunch of garbage links.

Comment: if you open that link (your "best so far" in your question), that page even suggests to add `&format=json` to the URL, i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=List_of_battles_1901%E2%80%932000&prop=links&format=json - does that help

Comment: Nope, the json formatting isnt really my issue.  The issue is trying to select only the battles that occured on April 3.  This is a hobby project I'm trying to do.  I would like to allow a user to go to a website and have a random historical battle that occured on that day in history pop up.  But I cant find a way using the wikipedia API to select pages from a list.  There is plenty of documentation about how to query categories, but that doesnt help me with these list pages.  I guess this might just plain not be possible using the wikipedia API, at least not in a feasible manner.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia and its API isn't really suited for semantic searching like this. Instead, you will probably have better luck using Wikidata, Wikipedia's sister site for structured data.

Wikidata has a SPARQL query service that you can use to find the information you want. (The examples have queries such as "List of countries ordered by the number of their cities with female mayor" and "Women with most sitelinks and no image born in 1921 or later".) Part of the data that you can query is a link to a relevant Wikipedia article, so you can filter your search by only battles that have a Wikipedia article. For more details, have a look at [Wikidata's SPARQL information page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service).

If it's important to you that the resulting articles are listed on Wikipedia's "List of battles 1901–2000" page, then you can cross-check the list you got from the SPARQL query service against Wikipedia's database. You could do this using the API, but probably the easiest way is to use [Quarry](https://quarry.wmflabs.org/) to query the replica database directly with SQL (this time MySQL, not SPARQL).